# Is it possible to execute a provisioner on a specific Vagrant machine after that machine's definition in the Vagrantfile has been ended?

Tags: vagrant, ansible, virtualbox

I'd like to be able to spin up all of my Vagrant VMs for a project at once and then, at the very end, execute Ansible (using ansible_local) on one of those VMs. Is it possible to have a provisioner such as ansible_local run on a machine you've already previously defined?

Example of what I want to do:

```
    # VM definitions
    config.vm.define "control" do |control|
        control.vm.hostname = "control.somedomain.local"
        control.vm.network "private_network", ip: "172.28.128.3"
        control.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |control_vbox|
            control_vbox.name = "Ansible Controller"
            control_vbox.cpus = 2
            control_vbox.memory = 1024
        end
    end
    config.vm.define "web01" do |web|
        control.vm.hostname = "web01.somedomain.local"
        control.vm.network "private_network", ip: "172.28.128.4"
        control.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |web_vbox|
            web_vbox.name = "Web Server 1"
            web_vbox.cpus = 2
            web_vbox.memory = 1024
        end
    end

    # run ansible_local provisioner from the control VM
    config.vm.provision "ansible_local" do |ansible|
        ansible.run_on_vm = "control"
        ansible.playbook = "some_playbook.yml"
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make the following change in your Vagrantfile

```
# VM definitions
config.vm.define "control" do |control|
    control.vm.hostname = "control.somedomain.local"
    control.vm.network "private_network", ip: "172.28.128.3"
    control.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |control_vbox|
        control_vbox.name = "Ansible Controller"
        control_vbox.cpus = 2
        control_vbox.memory = 1024
    end

    # run ansible_local provisioner from the control VM
    control.vm.provision "ansible_local" do |ansible|
        ansible.run_on_vm = "control"
        ansible.playbook = "some_playbook.yml"
    end
end
config.vm.define "web01" do |web|
    control.vm.hostname = "web01.somedomain.local"
    control.vm.network "private_network", ip: "172.28.128.4"
    control.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |web_vbox|
        web_vbox.name = "Web Server 1"
        web_vbox.cpus = 2
        web_vbox.memory = 1024
    end
end
```

so that the ansible provisioner will run only on the *control* VM

The other possibilities are

- running the vagrant command in following order

  ```
  $ vagrant up --no-provision // will spin up all the vms but will not provisiong
  $ vagrant provision control // will provision the control vm
  ```
- check the [vagrant trigger plugin](https://github.com/emyl/vagrant-triggers) which can be used to run specific command, I have not tested though with multi machine environment

Comment: This is not what I want. It will run the provisioner before the web01 VM exists, and thus it won't be able to run Ansible to configure it. I am aware that I can reorder them so that control comes last, but that is not the point of the question. I want to know if I can invoke the ansible_local provisioner after all the VMs have been created.